# Will multiple monitors or much bigger monitor affect computer performance?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, performance

I have two questions about the monitor's impact on the computer's performance:

1. Will multiple monitors affect computer performance?
2. will a bigger monitor (43") slow down the computer's performance compared with a smaller monitor (22")?

When we compare, we assume all monitors are full in live stock charts, these charts will be updated every second or shorter. Do you think more monitors or much bigger monitors will make the computer's response time longer? Is there a way to test this?

Comment: If you believe that you need quick human reactions to trade stocks you have already lost and should focus your attention elsewhere. Stocks will make you go broke. You are competing against people far smarter than you with far more resources who spend millions to shave a nanosecond or two off their trades https://www.npr.org/2014/04/01/297686724/on-a-rigged-wall-street-milliseconds-make-all-the-difference & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-frequency_trading

Answer (score 3):

More displays and more pixels DO impact system LOAD (see here: https://technofytrends.com/do-3-monitors-slow-down-computers/) but this does not necessarily mean the computer will run SLOWER.

Load could be seen as the percentage of a computer's resources that are being actively used at any moment. So long as there are resources available, each of the processes will complete in an adequate amount of time not to impact the system's speed. Once you have over loaded the system's resources, THEN a high load *may* impact the system's actual speed.

Frankly, your processing drain will be more about the data moving across the CPU and being computed, than it will be about any sort of GPU load, and much of that will depend on the software you're using to display all those data lines.

Like Gantendo said though: if you're at the place to be worried about driving those wiggly lines as quickly as you are able, you are FAR behind the profit curve. Real traders are using computer programs and dedicated fiber optic cables to order their trades far faster than your eyeballs and fingers can move.